# How soon can I use my shower that I recently grouted and tiled? Should it cure first?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, grout, tiling

We have been retiling my tub surround area and finished grouting the tile last night. I used non-sanded PolyBlend grout (sold at Home Depot) and added a bottle of [Grout Boost Advanced Pro](http://groutboost.com/consumer/products.cfm). Everything went okay, especially considering this was my first time tiling or grouting.

[image: My tub]

My question actually has to do with how soon we will be able to take a shower. I've been finding what I think is mixed information. The [Grout Boost Product Data Sheet](http://groutboost.com/pdfs/GB_AdvPro_PDS_ENG_042610.pdf) (pdf link) says:

> **Protection**
>
> Protect the finished installation from traffic or impact for at least 
>   24 hours; from water immersion or freezing for at least 10 days 
>   or per grout manufacturer’s instructions, whichever is longer. No 
>   need to seal grout. Clean up spills immediately upon occurrence. 
>   If a stain remains after initial cleanup, follow the recommended 
>   cleaning procedures provided at www.groutboost.com

And the [Grout Boost FAQ](http://www.groutboost.com/pdfs/GB_AdvncPro_FAQ.pdf) (pdf link) says:

> **How long after installation do you need to wait before using 
>   the area grouted?**
>
> The installation can be walked on at 24 hours.  Grout mixed with 
>   Grout Boost needs to cure for 10 days after installation before 
>   exposing it to water from mopping, showers, rain, etc.

I also saw a few comments online in forums saying that getting the grout + Grout Boost wet before the 10 days will only impact the stain resistance, not it's waterproofness.

So, how soon can I get it wet?

Comment: Looks like you did a great job.  Did you apply a waterproofing membrane behind it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sure looks like you did a beautiful job on your shower, be a crying shame to see all that hard work ruined with stained grout. The glazing agent in the grout needs 8 to 10 days to harden completely. I suggest that you tape up some poly to protect the new grout if you really need to use the shower before the prescribed cure time. A few days of inconvenience is definitely worth not having to scrub and look at stained grout for years to come.

Comment: You've convinced me - up goes the plastic! It's definitely been an experience. The only thing left now is to seal the tub with caulk. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not realistic to wait that long. Most people are like myself who have no way to shower while they were building one.

Let the grout dry for a day, seal it, wait another day, go for it. People on the internet will always tell you things need to cure for about 20 times longer than in reality. Also, the product manufacturers put WAY overboard cure times on the labels so that when something fails they can always say, "Oh you didn't let it cure long enough. Not our fault."

Comment: No need to pick one or the other. Taping up some plastic lets you use the shower while still keeping the grout dry.

Comment: We only have the single bathroom, and ended up hanging 0.9mil sheeting (the thinnest plastic painter's dropcloth we could find) over the walls with regular painter's tape. It was a little annoying to have all of that extra plastic hanging around you while you showered (the worst part was turning the shower knobs). It's been a year and a half and we've had no problems with the grout at all.

Answer (score 1):

Grout should CURE for up to 2 WEEKS.  It is not just a manufacturer cop out.  Getting water on the grout before then SLOWS the curing and allows breakdown, leading to cracking and chipping - the grout failing.  READ AND FOLLOW the directions.

Answer (score 0):

We have only ever let our grout cure 24 hours. We have soft water and we've never had any of it crumble or crack.