# Can I use my bathtub or shower during tiling project

Tags: shower, tiling

I would like to redo my shower tiling.  Demolition and then tiling may take longer than a day for me.  I only have one bathroom so I was wondering what milestones I should reach each day so I can still take a shower or use the bath tub?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How soon can I use my shower that I recently grouted and tiled? Should it cure first?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4980/2196)

Comment: Budget in a hotel room for a few days.

Comment: Or... if a hotel room doesn't fit the budget, a fitness center with showers works quite well.

Comment: It's going to take longer than you think, especially if you are alone.  My shower was my first tiling project, so what I did was create a small temporary shower to practice making the shower pan and installing tile.  It wasn't a bad idea.

Comment: Ah-Hah! - a use for the 30 day trial fitness center membership!

Comment: Also keep in mind the fact that it will tend to be the least usable when you are most in need of a shower from working on it...

Comment: Don't even think of trying to use the tub or shower during the rehab. It will end in disaster and ruin all your hard work.  Find a place to bathe elsewhere for a few days. Old fashion way, galv tub in the middle of the kitchen floor!!!  lolololol

Comment: you'd better do not use it until the work is done, suggest you to take shower at your friend's home.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are just replacing the tile and leaving the bathtub. So, you should have no problem taking a bath in the tub at any time during the tiling. As far as a shower, you can be creative with some polyethylene plastic taped or draped around the three walls and take a shower too throughout the project.