# Is it ok to use a shower that just has the backerboard installed and not yet tiled?

Tags: shower, tiling

I'm trying to figure out the timing of redoing my shower. I'm looking at installing a new tub with a tile surround. I'd like to demo the current setup and install the tub and backerboard (and sealant) one weekend and then do the tiling the next weekend.

Since this is my only shower, can I use the shower after putting up the backerboard and sealing it without yet tiling and not mess up the backerboard?

Comment: Get a membership to a local gym, and shower at the gym. If you hang out and exercise a bit, you'll also be a bit healthier as well as clean. Or hang some sheets of poly to cover the walls while you shower. Make sure the seams overlap, and no moisture gets behind the poly.

Comment: See also [How soon can I use my shower that I recently grouted and tiled? Should it cure first?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4980/2196)

Comment: take a bath instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a pan that is finished and given that your walls have either a membrane or a painted on membrane that is waterproof you could very lightly use the shower.  I would never endorse this if I was doing the job but if you are doing it yourself, then go ahead.  Make the showers short/light and make sure that it is bone dry before tiling.  (This is all given you have a waterproof membrane installed - the answer is no if you will be showering right on the backerboard.)

Answer (score 1):

It's the soap scum and body oils that I'd be worried about.  Residues could affect the how the tile bonds to the wall.  Put up some plastic sheeting over the wallboard for the week.